# How to make voice recognition check against a local database in android?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

Do you remember in old cellphones you could make a speech shortcut to call a person.

I am trying to make an app in android with that function. The user records a word or sound it wants to control the application with and the voice-recognizer will only check if the sound it hears equals the sound previously recorded.

Does anyone know how to make this or know of a guide? I've been searching for months without finding a satisfying solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert both reference sounds and recorded sound to features. For that you need to split sound on frames and extract FFT or directly mel-cepstrum. You can use any MFCC library out there for that.

After you get features, you can compare them with DTW algorithm. You can find some details here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping

The DTW will return you the threshold which you can use to select the right person to call to.

Similar quesitons is

[Simplest algorithm of measuring how similar of two short audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653466/simplest-algorithm-of-measuring-how-similar-of-two-short-audio)