# Recognize spoken phrase from previously recorded audio

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I am looking for a way to learn a phrase (1-2 words) from user (eg. let him repeat it 3 times) and then recognize it when it is said again.

I want to include it into an android app, so a library in java or C++ would be the best, but I am thankful for any help or hint.

Comment: Just to elaborate, I am looking for continuous recognition during the lifetime of my app. I unsuccesfully tried implementing it via [SpeechReecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) in android.

Comment: There is no such library, though the algorithm is simple. Related question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653466/simplest-algorithm-of-measuring-how-similar-of-two-short-audio

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763419/how-to-make-voice-recognition-check-against-a-local-database-in-android?lq=1