# android app to do recognition of one phrase or word all the time

Tags: speech-recognition, speech, speech-synthesis

i am developing an android app with the following features:

> after the app is installed, it will ask for a phrase/word to record which would act as an activator 
>   the app will run in background all the time and would be listening to anything the user has to say, and would be matching it with the phrase it recorded just after the app was installed
>   To implement this, i can think of two ways:
>   i) use a readymade speech recogniser like google, pocketspinx etc
>   ii) since i do not have a long list of words to recognise, i simply need to match whether the phrase that was recorded is being repeated ever or not, the feature is more like 'OK Google' feature of google search on smartphones. i do not even need to convert the speech into words, just match whether the speech matches with the recording or not.
>   note: i do not want to use readymade speech recognition APIs as regular recognition(every second) may compromise the working of smartphones. i have tried google speech recognition and it made my phone go all dizzy. i want to be use as much less resources as possible

Comment: Welcome to SO. As it stands, its hard to help you without seeing what you have actually done and it sounds like you are asking for someone to do this task for you. What do you mean by _made my phone go all dizzy_? What were the results from Google's API? Since you don't want to use a readymade speech API, then it seems like u need to write one from scratch. What effort have you kept in doing this? Please review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make voice recognition check against a local database in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763419/how-to-make-voice-recognition-check-against-a-local-database-in-android)