# How to compare two audio files to check if they have a similar sound

Tags: audio, voice-recognition, audio-fingerprinting

I have a situation here. Suppose I have two short audio files which contains some sounds. Suppose, first file has sound 'hello'(audio 1) and second file has 'bye'(audio 2) spoken by someone. There is another audio file which has 'hello'(audio 3) spoken by the same person but is a different recording.

How can I detect that audio 3 is similar to audio 1 (irrespective of the speaker)? I'm here dealing with sounds and not only speech. So there can be a whistle sound also in place of the words.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest algorithm of measuring how similar of two short audio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653466/simplest-algorithm-of-measuring-how-similar-of-two-short-audio)

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Thank you, I will have a look.

Comment: I've answered a similar question [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891629/comparing-two-recorded-voices

Answer (score -1):

You would have to program a statistical analysis of each file, then use pattern matching to determine the level of similarity between them.

The simplest solution for words would be to license an api version of a speech engine such as Dragon, then convert the audio files to text output and compare them.