# Audio Comparing/ Audio Fingerprinting In Iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio, compare

The problem is that i want to compare **two sounds** together and check how much **similarity** is in between two **Voice/Sounds**.

**Example** : There is **"A"** pronunciation already stored in app and the user **say/record** **"A"** in his/her voice and then we **compare** both and give result **how much %** they are **same**.

I searched **GitHub** and **stack overflow** for answer but didn't got any authentic and proper solution for this.

Can anybody share any **library** or **code snippet** for **help**.

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: Please Check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653466/simplest-algorithm-of-measuring-how-similar-of-two-short-audio

Comment: I checked the link you shared already. I want any library or something already made for this purpose.

Comment: @SyedUzairAhmed for free?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw yes ofcourse..